# dompdf making the header and the footer "solid"

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

Hi i'm saving some html stuff with .pdf extension using dompdf.
The problem is that i made an header and a footer(using the dompdf script) and it looks fine as long as content does not fill the whole page.

The thing is that the header and the footer generated act like an absolute positioned div and the page content goes under them instead of jumping to the next page once the footer is reached.

Now, i know they are added after the html and it's normal that the text goes under but is there anyway(maybe with some kind of html/css solution) to make a solid div that, once "reached" by the div above makes it jump to the next free space available on the page?

Any work around?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem giving the body tag a margin top equal to the header height and a margin bottom equal to the footer height this automatically applies to every page.